# Update each button item inside a list instead of all buttons at once in Swift / SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm currently trying to change a button from one view to another depending on what the user presses. They would get a list/scrollview of pending requests and if the user clicks on accept, it should change that button to an accepted button and if the user clicks on reject, it should change that button to a rejected button. I'm running into a problem where if a user clicks on accept, all the pending request buttons gets changed to an accepted button and similarly for the reject case.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine


struct BottomSheet: View {
    
//    @ObservedObject var userData : UserViewModel
    
    var edges = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets
    
 
    @StateObject var userData = UserViewModel()

    @State var declinedRequest: Bool = false

    @State var acceptedRequest: Bool = false
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            Spacer()
            
            VStack(spacing: 12){
                
               
                Divider()
               
                
                
                   
                    // here are the buttons inside the scrollview 
                    ScrollView{
                        ForEach(userData.pendingFriendUsers){ person in
                            
                            HStack{
                                if person.pic != ""{
                                    WebImage(url: URL(string: person.pic)!)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                        .padding(.leading, 30)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 10)


                                }else{
                                    Circle()
                                        .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 2)
                                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                        .padding(.leading, 20)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 10)

                                }
                                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                    Text("\(person.name)")
                                        .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 16))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.white).bold()
                                    Text("@\(person.username)")
                                        .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 16))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                        .opacity(0.8)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                
                                if person.isFriends == 2 {
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                                        .fill(Color("Dark-Grey"))
                                        .frame(width: 150, height: 40)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 25)
                                        .overlay(
                                            Text("Request removed")
                                                .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 14))
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                                .padding(.trailing, 25)
                                        )
                                }else if person.isFriends == 1 {
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                                        .fill(Color.white)
                                        .frame(width: 150, height: 40)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 25)
                                        .overlay(
                                            Text("Request accepted")
                                                .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 14))
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                                .padding(.trailing, 25)
                                        )
                                }else {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        print("declined friend request for \(person.uid)")
                                        withAnimation(){declinedRequest = true}
                                        userData.declineFriendRequest(otherUserUID: person.uid)

                                    }){
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous)
                                            .fill(Color("Dark-Grey"))
                                            .frame(width: 55, height: 26.5)
                                            .padding(.trailing, 13)
                                            .overlay(
                                                Image("x")
                                                    .renderingMode(.template)
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                                    .opacity(0.8)
                                                    .frame(width: 12, height: 12)
                                                    .padding(.trailing, 12)
                                            )
                                    }
                                   
                                    Button(action: {
                                        print("accepted friend request for \(person.uid)")
                                        withAnimation(){acceptedRequest = true}
                                        userData.acceptFriendRequest(otherUserUID: person.uid)

                                    }){
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                                        .fill(Color.white)
                                        .frame(width: 50, height: 25)
                                        .padding(.trailing, 35)
                                        .overlay(
                                            Image("check")
                                                .resizable()
                                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                                .padding(.trailing, 33)
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                
                            }.padding(.top, 12.5)
                            
                        }
            
                    }
                       
            
                        
                    Spacer()
                    
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 1.15)
            .padding(.top)
            .background(Color("gray")
                            .clipShape(CustomCorner(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight])))
            .offset(y: offset)
            // bottom sheet remove swipe gesture....
            .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged(onChanged(value:)).onEnded(onEnded(value:)))
            .offset(y: showSheet ? 0 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(
            Color.black.opacity(showSheet ? 0.3 : 0).ignoresSafeArea()
                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                    withAnimation{showSheet.toggle()}
                })
        )
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

When declinedRequest or acceptedRequest get modified, its not mapped to the button so everything in the for view gets changed instead of the individual button. I've added my basic code below but some things I tried are making a published variable in my user data model class but it doesn't get updated in the for each as it moves on by then and I also tried making a published variable here. It looks like I have something to do with indices and mapping but I'm unsure what the best approach is. Thanks for your help

Edit:
Here's relevant sections from my user view model:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Combine
import Foundation



struct pendingFriendUser: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var uid: String
    var name: String
    var username: String
    var pic: String
    var isFriends: Int
    
    
    init(id: Int, uid: String, name: String, username: String, pic: String, isFriends: Int){
        self.id = id
        self.uid = uid
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.pic = pic
        self.isFriends = isFriends
    }
}



class UserViewModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var userInfo = UserModel(username: "", pic: "", name: "", age: 1, uid: "", phoneNumber: "")
    
    let ref = Firestore.firestore()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
 
    @Published var pendingFriendUsers: [pendingFriendUser]

    //show add friends sheet
    @AppStorage("showSheet") var showSheet = false

    //check friendship variabe
    @Published var isFriend = 0
    
    

    init() {
        self.searchedUsers = []
        
        self.pendingFriendUsers = []
        
        fetchUser(uid: uid) { (user) in
                    self.userInfo = user
        }
    }
func getPendingRequests(){
        //check if friends has any false memberships
        var pendingFriendRequests: [String: Bool] = [:]
        self.ref.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument(){
            (document, err) in
            
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents \(err)")
            } else {
                
                if document!.data()!["friends"] != nil {
                    pendingFriendRequests = document!.data()!["friends"] as! [String : Bool]
                }
                
                //filter based on false pending friend requests
                self.pendingFriendUsers.removeAll()

                var friendUserID = 0 
                for key in pendingFriendRequests.keys {
                    if pendingFriendRequests[key] == false {
                        self.ref.collection("Users").document(key).getDocument(){
                            (friendDocument, err) in
                            
                            if let err = err {
                                print("Error getting documents \(err)")
                            } else {
                                let pendingFriendUsername = (friendDocument?.data()?["username"]) as! String
                                let pendingFriendUID = (friendDocument?.data()?["uid"]) as! String
                                let pendingFriendName = (friendDocument?.data()?["name"]) as! String
                                let pendingFriendPic = (friendDocument?.data()?["imageurl"]) as! String

                                self.pendingFriendUsers.append(pendingFriendUser(id: friendUserID, uid: pendingFriendUID , name: pendingFriendName , username: pendingFriendUsername, pic: pendingFriendPic, isFriends: 0))
                                
                                friendUserID += 1

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

   ...
    func acceptFriendRequest(otherUserUID: String){
        for var pendingFriend in pendingFriendUsers {
            if pendingFriend.uid == otherUserUID {
                pendingFriend.isFriends = 1
            }
        }
        self.ref.collection("Users").document(self.uid).setData(
            [ "friends": [
                otherUserUID: true
            ] ]
            , merge: true)
        
        self.ref.collection("Users").document(otherUserUID).setData(
            [ "friends": [
                self.uid: true
            ] ]
            , merge: true)
    }
    
    func declineFriendRequest(otherUserUID: String){
        for var pendingFriend in pendingFriendUsers {
            if pendingFriend.uid == otherUserUID {
                pendingFriend.isFriends = 2
            }
        }
        
        self.ref.collection("Users").document(self.uid).updateData([
            "friends.\(otherUserUID)": FieldValue.delete(),
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error updating document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully updated")
            }
        }
    }
    func checkFriendRequest(otherUserUID: String){
        
        //0 if not found in friend list or friend request
        //1 means theyre friends
        //2 means that user sent self/me a friend request
        var pendingFriendRequests: [String: Bool] = [:]
        self.ref.collection("Users").document(self.uid).getDocument(){
            (document, err) in
            
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents \(err)")
            } else {
                pendingFriendRequests = document!.data()!["friends"] as! [String : Bool]
                

                for key in pendingFriendRequests.keys {
                    if key == otherUserUID{

                        if pendingFriendRequests[key] == true {
                            self.isFriend = 1
                        }else if pendingFriendRequests[key] == false {
                            self.isFriend = 2
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Edited with isFriends variable

Comment: I don't believe there's enough code or information here to really give a good solution. You need some method to store `accepted` and `declined` for each user. But, you haven't shared your `UserViewModel` or any information about how the friend requests are reflected in your model or back end. Seems like it should be relatively straightforward to have a property on each `User` saying whether they are a friend or not.

Comment: its not related to the user view model as Im focusing on when the user presses the accepted or declined button to change the button view inside the scroll view

Comment: Right, but you only have one accepted or declined state right now. You need a place to store a state for each user. The logical place to do that is in the view model, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Hmm yea I think I can do it like that in the view model by reading the database again to see if they're friends but was wondering whether it was possible to not have to perform a read query

Comment: Like I was saying, there's not enough info here to make a recommendation about that, since there's no info about how everything is stored. You could do a write request modifying the friendship state and then modify your local state to reflect that without doing a read. But, you may already have something like a `snapshotListener` in Firebase, for example, that will get the new data automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've added relevant sections from my user view model. I guess I can use my checkFriendRequest for each button somehow to determine what it should look like but it seems like an unnecessary amount of read requests that I would like to get by if I can

Comment: Why not just add a `friends` property to your `pendingFriendUser` (you should capitalize type names in Swift, btw) model and update it when the request is accepted if you're concerned about that? Downside is that if the accept failed (network connection issue or something), your state would be out of sync.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't update the button in real time. Like the following: if person.friends == 2 { //reject confirmed button } else if person.friends == 1 { //accept confirmed button} else { //default accept or reject button}. I added it as a friends int value in my pendingFriendUser

Comment: And how are you modifying the value? Can you update your question with the new code?

Comment: I just updated my code with the isFriends variable that I added to the pendingFriendUser. I loop through with the for var pendingFriendUser in the accept and decline methods in userviewmodel and initialize it with a value of 0. Thanks again

Comment: You aren’t actually modifying the instance in the array. You’re mutating a copy. Do you know how to modify the version actually in the array or would it be helpful to see an answer that shows you how to do that?

Comment: O I'm sorry I don't believe I do know how to modify the version in the array. Any resource or tips you can point towards would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you have this:

```
for var pendingFriend in pendingFriendUsers {
   if pendingFriend.uid == otherUserUID {
     pendingFriend.isFriends = 1
   }
}
```

This doesn't actually modify anything in `pendingFriendUsers`, because `pendingFriendUser` is a `struct`, which gets passed by value in Swift, not by reference. So `var pendingFriend` is a *copy* of the version in `pendingFriendUsers`.

Instead, you could do something like this:

```
self.pendingFriendUsers = self.pendingFriendUsers.map { pendingFriend in
  guard pendingFriend.uid == otherUserUID else { return pendingFriend } //return the original if the UID doesn't match
  var modified = pendingFriend //make a mutable copy
  modified.isFriends = 1
  return modified //return the modified version
}
```

or:

```
guard let index = self.pendingFriendUsers.firstIndex(where: { $0.uid == otherUserUID }) else { return } //get the index of the matching UID
self.pendingFriendUsers[index].isFriends = 1 //modify the item at that index
```

Comment: This worked amazingly! I modified it as following: if let index = pendingFriendUsers.firstIndex(where: {$0.uid == otherUserUID}) {
            pendingFriendUsers[index].isFriends = 2
        }